# Error converting data type nvarchar to numeric while converting phone number

Tags: sql-server

```
INSERT INTO PHONE_NUMBERS(
         [OWNER_ID]
        , OWNER_TYPE_ID
        , PHONE_NUMBER_TYPE_ID
        , AREA_CODE
        , PREFIX
        , PHONE_NUMBER_BODY
        , IS_ACTIVE)
    SELECT   
        INS_COMPANY_ID
        , @OWNER_TYPE_ID OWNER_TYPE_ID
        , @PHONE_NUMBER_TYPE_ID PHONE_NUMBER_TYPE_ID 
        , LEFT(try_convert(varchar(50), cast(([Insurance Phone]) as decimal(38,0) ) ),3)
        , substring( try_convert(varchar(50), cast(([Insurance Phone]) as decimal(38,0) ) ),4,3)PREFIX
        , RIGHT(try_convert(varchar(50), cast(([Insurance Phone]) as decimal(38,0) ) ),4)
        , 1 IS_ACTIVE
    FROM
        Insurance_Companies_28012020 EE
    JOIN
        INS_COMPANIES IC ON ee.[Insurance Name] = IC.COMPANY_NAME  
    WHERE
        ic.is_active = 1 AND [Insurance Phone] IS NOT NULL
```

Here my `Phone` is like `895-541-8541`. This phone data is imported from Excel and table data type is `varchar`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `cast(([Insurance Phone]) as decimal` won't work if there are dashes in the string.

There is no reason to cast to a decimal before converting to varchar.  If `Insurance Phone` is truly a varchar column, then there is a lot of unnecessary casting and converting in your query:

```
INSERT INTO  
PHONE_NUMBERS( [OWNER_ID]  
 , OWNER_TYPE_ID  
 , PHONE_NUMBER_TYPE_ID  
, AREA_CODE  
, PREFIX  
, PHONE_NUMBER_BODY  
 , IS_ACTIVE  
)  
 SELECT INS_COMPANY_ID  
 , @OWNER_TYPE_ID OWNER_TYPE_ID  
 , @PHONE_NUMBER_TYPE_ID PHONE_NUMBER_TYPE_ID   
, LEFT([Insurance Phone], 3)  
 , substring( [Insurance Phone],4,3) PREFIX  
 , RIGHT([Insurance Phone],4)  
, 1 IS_ACTIVE   
FROM Insurance_Companies_28012020 EE  
 join INS_COMPANIES IC on ee.[Insurance Name] =IC.COMPANY_NAME where ic.is_active=1 and [Insurance Phone] is not null
```

Comment: So can you help me? How should I code to get the desired answer?

Comment: Updated with sample SQL.

Comment: Thanks a lot, by reading your comment "There is no reason to cast to a decimal before converting to varchar" I have tried same,
, LEFT([Insurance Phone], 3)  
 , substring( [Insurance Phone],4,3) PREFIX  
 , RIGHT([Insurance Phone],4)  
And now seeing your reply is perfectly matching. 

Thanks a lot, Willman.

Comment: Hi Williman, 
I have made a little mistake and now got more to work. 
Can you help me?

Comment: It it is a new problem, please post it as a new question.